# Does jna.library.path use any environment variables?

Tags: java, jna

On OS X 10.8.2, I'm using JNA and gstreamer-java (through the Eclipse IDE) to load gstreamer libraries. At first I installed gstreamer using the SDK provided by [gstreamer.com](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X). However, I uninstalled this and use Macports to install it.

The SDK's libs *were* installed to:
`/System/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/0.10-x64/lib`

But that directory no longer exists.

Where Macports installed the libs to:

`/opt/local/lib`

Now, say I want to set java to know of this location via some environment variable. Is this possible? It seems so, because running this line:

`System.out.println( System.getProperty("jna.library.path"));`

Shows `/System/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/0.10-x64/lib`. But I cannot for the life of me figure out where that got set. It's not set as a runtime VM argument. My $PATH and $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH do not have this directory set. They actually have the path I want, `/opt/local/lib/` set which has no effect it seems. Running `env` shows no variables with the Framework path either.

So, `jna.library.path`. Is it set externally? How can I change it--without setting it at runtime or via java command-line arguments? Zero points for telling me to symlink.

**EDIT:**

Searching through gstreamer-java's files led me to `gstreamer-java.spec`, which has this line:

`sed -i [...] -e "s,\(run.jvmargs=-Djna.library.path=\).*,\1%{_libdir}:$(pkg-config --variable=pluginsdir gstreamer-0.10),"`

Running the contained command `pkg-config --variable=pluginsdir gstreamer-0.10` gets me this:

`/opt/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10`

Which is the correct path for plugins. Further running `pkg-config --print-variables gstreamer-0.10` gives me all these:

```
typelibdir
datarootdir
exec_prefix
pluginsdir
datadir
prefix
libdir
includedir
girdir
toolsdir
```

Which are all at or under the correct `/opt/local/` directory.

Comment: JNA does not set this variable itself.  It's possible that some part of your GStreamer installation is setting it.   What is the value when you omit or do not import the gstreamer mappings?  It's entirely possible that there is some static code within the gstreamer mappings which sets the path.

Comment: It is the same `/System/Library/...` path. I've found some other stuff too, I'll update the question.

Comment: Apparently running the `pkg-config` command in the context of `gstreamer-java.spec` is different than your shell context.  Maybe you just need to re-run `pkg-config` and friends?  You can at least hard-code the new path into the `gstreamer-java.spec` to see whether it's still in play in affecting your execution environment.

Comment: I've cleaned and rebuilt gstreamer-java, thinking that the path got built in to the JAR somehow. But, it doesn't seem to have changed anything. To verify, I created a new Java project without any dependancies and printed out the jna.library.path, which gives me the same System Framework path.

Comment: Have you tried running outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Put that last comment as an answer. The Gstreamer installer seems to have set default VM arguments under Eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse's default VM arguments from the Preferences pane was setting the jna.library.path. It seems most of my questions on SO are due to my lack of proper isolation.